# Fetching Latest 2 records from Lookback API

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

We are in situation where We Need to fetch last two records from Lookback API every time .

For the below case, we need the records highlighted in green,

[image]

We are doing the incremental fetch using the ***_ValidFrom*** Date in Lookback API.
We need last two records so that we can handle the updates happening to ***_ValidTo*** whenever new snapshot is created.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that data from just the most recent snapshot can't you?  The _ValidFrom of the most recent should be equal to the _ValidTo of the second to last one.

Comment: We can, But we dont want to do the updates at our end as thats not technically feasible for us, We want to get the Data as it looks now from Agile Central Itself